# Vim: moving the cursor to a string in a source file without error messages if it doesn't exist

Tags: vim

When I use vi to open a file *.c, I would like the cursor to move to the string "main" automatically. If there is no "main", I want the cursor to go to "void" without an error prompt.

In my `.vimrc` I have set

```
:autocmd BufRead *.c 1;/main
```

but this cannot implement all my requirements. Specifically, if there exists no "main" in some opened C source file, vi prompts "Error, cannot find main ...." which is the behaviour I want to remove.

I have also tried adding `<silent>` or `:silent` to that `autocmd` line, but it doesn't do what I want. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `:silent!`; it runs a given command blocking not only the
normal messages but also the errors.

I would recommend to use the `BufReadPost` event instead of `BufRead`
to run your command *after* the buffer is loaded, and change the
search pattern to look for `main` as a separate word:

```
:autocmd BufReadPost *.c :silent! 1;/\<main\>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to implement structure control in vimrc such as If-else structure. For example, if there is "main", cursor go to "main" and if no "main", cursor go to "void".

Comment: If/else structure is not complicated, just take a look at `:help if`.  To search you could use `search` function that returns line number where occurrence has been found or zero (without raising an error).  For example `:if search('\<main\>') == 0 | call search('\<void\>') | endif`  This command tests whether or not word "main" could be found starting from current cursor position, and if not (search returns zero) calling search function for "void"

Comment: So you could transform your autocmd to something like that: `:autocmd BufReadPost *.c :silent! 1 | if search('\<main\>') == 0 | call search('\<void\>') | endif`  Note that several statements on one line should be separated with `|`. Also, for calling function outside of Vim command (`if`, `while`, `let`, etc.) it's necessary to use `call`.

Answer (score 0):

Try /main\|^, but if cursor in file not on first line - it's not that you want.